# Split Apart Formatted Numbers & Assign As Variables

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Titanium IDE, in JavaScript. I think this is going to have to happen using Regex, as well.

So, I'm trying to take something like
`5-6-7`
and split it up so that, for example,
I take the first number (in this case, 5), and then bring that into a variable to use later on. This would be the same for all the numbers, so that I end up with something like `var one = 5; var two = 6; var three = 7;`

That way, I'd be able to take specific digits and use their values instead of taking it as a whole.

I've been working on this for about two hours now, but since my understanding of Regex or other similar text formatting) is pretty bad at this point (learning!), I could use the extra help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can access the data like this:

```
var list = "1-6-7-123-123-3-21-3",
    items = list.split('-');

console.log(items[1]); // logs "6"
console.log(items[0]); // logs "1"
console.log(items[3]); // logs "123"
```

Comment: +1. I was about to post the same answer. Regex is overkill for this problem. Note though that the array will contain _strings_, not numbers.

Comment: Thanks for changing from comment to answer. Great help!

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah good point... maybe run a parseInt before manipulating anything if you need them to be INTs.

Comment: @JTApps Thanks :) I think you can use regex within the split function too if the need arises.